# Selecting elements with specific namespaced attributes

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, xml-namespaces, inkscape

My problem is specifically about some trouble I'm having parsing an Inkscape (XML) file, but it's solution should be applicable to any XML doc, so I feel it's Stackoverflow relevant.

I'm trying to use the Nokogiri CSS selectors to get all the `<g>` elements that have the attribute `inkscape:groupmode="layer"`.  But the colon is causing the error:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected ':' after 'inkscape'
```

My XML document looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="744.09448819" height="1052.3622047" id="svg3720" version="1.1" inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760" sodipodi:docname="test.svg">
  <defs id="defs3722">
    <inkscape:perspective sodipodi:type="inkscape:persp3d" inkscape:vp_x="0 : 526.18109 : 1" inkscape:vp_y="0 : 1000 : 0" inkscape:vp_z="744.09448 : 526.18109 : 1" inkscape:persp3d-origin="372.04724 : 350.78739 : 1" id="perspective3728"/>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:zoom="0.35" inkscape:cx="375" inkscape:cy="634.28571" inkscape:document-units="px" inkscape:current-layer="g2818" showgrid="false" inkscape:window-width="550" inkscape:window-height="483" inkscape:window-x="66" inkscape:window-y="471" inkscape:window-maximized="0"/>
  <metadata id="metadata3725">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
        <dc:title/>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g inkscape:label="Layer 1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer1">
    <rect style="fill:#d2e149;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" id="rect2812" width="211.42857" height="128.57143" x="168.57143" y="215.21933" ry="64.285713"/>
  </g>
  <g inkscape:label="Layer 1 copy copy" inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="g2818">
    <rect style="fill:#d2e149;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" id="rect2820" width="211.42857" height="128.57143" x="145.71428" y="615.2193" ry="64.285713"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

My selector looks like:

```ruby
nokogiri_document.css('[inkscape:groupmode="layer"]').to_html
```

I also tried replacing the colon with a pipe

How do I write the CSS selector to work on the `inkscape:groupmode` attribute...or for that matter any `foo:bar` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath, specifying the namespace for the `g` elements. Since your root element declares the `xmlns:svg` to be the same as the new default namespace (`xmlns`) you can use `svg` as your prefix:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(IO.read('contents.xml'))
layers = doc.xpath('//svg:g[@inkscape:groupmode="layer"]')

p layers.map{ |layer| layer['id'] }
#=> ["layer1", "g2818"]
```

Decoded, the above XPath says:

- **`//`** - At any level of the document
- **`svg:g`** - …find `g` elements with a namespace matching the `svg` namespace
- **`[…]`** - …but only if the contents of this are met
- **`@inkscape:groupmode`** - …there is an attribute (`@`) named `groupmode` with a namespace matching `inkscape`
- **`="layer"`** - and the intrinsic value of this attribute is the text `layer`.

Alternatively, if you're just trying to read this file (and not manipulate and re-save it) you can use the gross-but-simplifying hack of removing all namespaces. In this case, your original code works simply:

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
p doc.css('g[groupmode="layer"]').map{ |g| g['id'] }
#=> ["layer1", "g2818"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try to use XPath. Look at this snippet:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('your_file.xml'))
doc.xpath('//xmlns:g[starts-with(@inkscape:label, "Layer")]').size  # => 2
```

Please pay attention at `xmlns` in XPath expression. Because XPath query looks for elements that are not in any namespace, you need to tell your XPath processor that you are looking for elements in given namespace. You can do this by several ways. I use most simple case - the using the default namespace in XPath query. Also you can define a custom namespace in the second argument of the XPath method call and use that in the query.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right, I made a blunder. I'll correct my snippet. Thanks

Comment: Ooh, shame on me :) I've made an example for `inkscape:label` attribute instead of `inkscape:groupmode` as author wanted. But I think leave my snippet as is because it may be helpful as example of slight more enhanced facilities of the attribute searching. Anyway many thanks for so useful comments